# Accessing dynamically created iframe within imacros

Tags: iframe, imacros

I need help with implementing an imacros script.

My basis script looks like this:

```
VERSION BUILD=8940826 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=URL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=NAME:login-custnum CONTENT=12345
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=NAME:login-username CONTENT=myuser
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD ATTR=NAME:login-password CONTENT=password
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=NAME:login-login
```

This script works, the login is performed.

After this I need to use one of 3 iframes.
I cannot use

```
 FRAME NAME="menu_iframe"
```

because the frames are created dynamically and NOT statically.

I tried the following:

```
var myframe = window.frames["menu_iframe"];
```

But this does not work.

After that I want to click a certain button in that iframe.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First of all I suggest checking the frame names. Try the macro below that consists of only one line. It must show names of all frames on the page with ‘alert’ dialog.

```
URL GOTO=javascript:{window.location.href='javascript:{var<SP>f=[];var<SP>l=window.frames.length;for(i=0;i<l;i++){try{f.push("\\""+window.frames[i].name+"\\"");}catch(e){f.push("no_frame_name")}}alert("FOUND<SP>"+f.length+"<SP>FRAMES:"+"\\n\\n"+f.join("\\n"));}';undefined;}
```